# Ms Team custom Tab application is not showing setup button with new Ms team

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

Ms Team custom Tab application is not showing setup button with new MS team.While I'm installing my custom personal tab app, setup button is not showing in new MS team, but same things that work in old MS team app version.

Import that setup file from new tab:

```
add -> Manage app -> upload app
```

[image: Setup showing]

Here is the code of Manifest file :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.16",
  "id": "180956bb-8d3c-4d89-98d7-a3895f5d3fd1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageName": "com.custom.tab",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Contoso",
    "websiteUrl": "https://tab-personal.azurewebsites.net",
    "privacyUrl": "https://tab-personal.azurewebsites.net/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://tab-personal.azurewebsites.net/tou",
    "mpnId": ""
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Tab",
    "full": "personalTab"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "short description here",
    "full": "full description here"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "outline.png",
    "color": "color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [],
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "index",
      "name": "Personal Tab",
      "contentUrl": "https://tab-personal.azurewebsites.net/PersonalTab",
      "websiteUrl": "https://tab-personal.azurewebsites.net/PersonalTab",
      "scopes": [
        "personal", 
        "groupChat",
        "team"
      ],
      "context": [
        "personalTab",  
           "privateChatTab", 
           "meetingChatTab", 
           "meetingDetailsTab", 
           "meetingSidePanel", 
           "meetingStage",
           "channelTab"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bots": [],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "tab-personal.azurewebsites.net"
  ]
}
```

[Log Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3kge.png)

Comment: Hi Ronak - We have tried to repro this issue, but we can see a 'Set up a tab' after uploading custom tab application - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIUUN.png

Comment: Do I need any pre-configuration/enable policy? because it's work in team classic app version.

Comment: It is not required to set any pre-configuration/enable policy.

Comment: I also tried same things with another tenant but facing same issue.

Comment: Hi Ronak,
Could you please share the error logs. So, we can check that from our end.

Comment: We have checked with web version and not found any log over there.